# Cannot start AcrobatReader or open the document - Winshell

Tags: errors, viewers

When i try to PDFView Command in Winshell I'm getting the below error. I'm using Winshell 3.3.2.4

[image]

Comment: Obvious question, I know, but do you have Acrobat installed (or some other PDF viewer)? What do you see in Execute -> Program Calls for 'PDFView'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. If the Acrobat Reader is not open and if I try to give PDFView command it prompts the above error.

However When I kept open the Acrobat Reader and give the PDFView command it works.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=132#p5997) fixed the problem for me.

Long story short: it seems that AcrobatReader is sometimes very unhappy with relative paths to a file so you have to spoonfeed him the absolute path. This can be done by using the following script instead of the plain Reader executable:

```
@start "" "C:\path\to\where\you\have\AcroRd32.exe" "%~f1"
```

What disturbs me a bit is that the post that solves the problem is from 2008 but the problem occurred after a very recent update.